# Why does .map produce a row of nils when used to enumerate over hashes?

Tags: ruby

```
test = 
 {:content=>"type_name", :content_length=>9, :array_index=>0},
 {:content=>"product_id", :content_length=>10, :array_index=>1},
 {:content=>"First Item", :content_length=>10, :array_index=>0},
 {:content=>"1111", :content_length=>4, :array_index=>1}

pp  test.map {|x| puts x} #=> 
{:content=>"type_name", :content_length=>9, :array_index=>0}
{:content=>"product_id", :content_length=>10, :array_index=>1}
{:content=>"First Item", :content_length=>10, :array_index=>0}
{:content=>"1111", :content_length=>4, :array_index=>1}
[nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

What is the cause of that array of nils? The map works perfectly, but then it causes these nils!

Comment: That's the return value you're seeing in irb.  `puts` returns `nil` and you are seeing 4 `nil`s returned from 4 `puts` calls.

Comment: Do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: Nah, you can have it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Argh what a stupid error!
This fixes it:

```
test.map {|x| puts x}
```

I was pretty printing the puts statement, and irb, trying to be helpful, returned nil four times!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that #map is designed to *transform an array into a different array*.  Generally, the block of #map will not have side effects.  Here's a use of #map to double all the numbers in an array:

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |n| n * 2}    # => [2, 4, 6]
```

If the purpose of your loop is solely to have side effects (such as printing the elements), you want #each instead:

```
[1, 2, 3].each { |n| puts n }
# => 1
# => 2
# => 3
```

In this case, we don't care about the return value of #each.  All we care about is that each number gets printed.